# Find column Value by dividing with sum of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, netezza

I have a table with the following columns in a Netezza Database

```
Id  field1  field2      
 1   0.9    sum(field1)/0.9
 2   1.7    sum(field1)/1.7
 3   6.9    sum(field1)/6.9
 4   0.4    sum(field1)/0.4
 5   0.2    sum(field1)/0.2
 6   2.8    sum(field1)/2.8
 7   7.0    sum(field1)/7.0
```

The `field2` column is to be generated and will hold values as shown in the table.

For this example the sum of `field1` is `19.9`.

Also the `field1` values will change frequently.

Please help with  a query that will help calculate the `field2` value also the values are in decimals so will want the precise sum.

Thanks

Comment: Based on your second sample of data what should the result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) with the [OVER Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) .

```
select Id,
       field1,
       (sum(field1) over() / field1) as field2
from YourTable
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f65c3/1/0)

Comment: Also how to change the query to do the following computation 0.9/sum(field1) ?

Comment: Hi Mikael,

Please also help with this query

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086194/grouping-and-dividing-netezza

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`OUTER APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select t1.id,
  t1.field1,
  (t2.field1 / t1.field1) field2
from table1 t1
outer apply
(
  select sum(field1) field1
  from table1
) t2
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f152/7)

If you don't have access to `outer apply` then you can use a cartesian result query:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.field1,
  (t2.field1 / t1.field1) field2
from table1 t1, 
(
  select sum(field1) field1
  from table1
) t2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f152/9)

Comment: Netezza does not support the OUTER APPLY clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.*, (b.totalSum / a.field1)
FROM    table1 a
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT SUM(filed1) totalSum
            FROM tableName
        ) b
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e418/2)